# MySQL: How to redirect source command output?

Tags: mysql-cli

If I execute

```
tee /tmp/script.log
source /root/myscript.sql
```

I get the log in `script.log` and in my current prompt session.

I want to execute `myscript.sql` and don't show anything in my prompt, only save it in `script.log`

I've tried mysql -s (--silent), but then no log is generated in `script.log`.

I need to use `source` command, `mysql < myscript.sql` is not userfull because it leave the session when its finish, and I have `flush tables with read lock` command in the end of the script, if the session leaves, `flush tables with read lock` is terminated.

Answer (score 1):

```
( cat myscript.sql && read ) | mysql
```

Because `read` is pausing waiting for input,  the input to `mysql` doesn't finish, and `mysql` doesn't exit. So the lock held by `FLUSH TABLES WITH READ LOCK` stays active as long as you want.

When you want to terminate the `read`, just hit return. Or type anything, as long as it doesn't cause an error as input to `mysql`.

If you want it to terminate itself after say 60 seconds, you could alternatively do this:

```
( cat myscript.sql && sleep 60 ) | mysql
```